# Using MySQL in multithreaded PHP script ends up to error "MySQL server has gone away"

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, parallel-processing, firebase-cloud-messaging

This question is a little complex so I will first sum up the context :

My app needs to deliver a important amount of push notificaton at a very precise time. FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging, remote service that delivers the push notification to the devices), has a maximum of 500 push notification per HTTP request.

I couldn't simply loop over pending push notifications in database and send them to FCM without threads , because I would have to wait the response of each request before sending the following.

Therefore, I created a PHP script in the aim of sending N payloads of 500 push notifications to FCM in N http request sent parellely. I used "parallel" PHP librairy, which is the new standard to have PHP with multithreading, as I understood.

The script does that :

```
// THIS IS THE THREAD CALLBACK : 
$sendNotificationBatch = static function(
    string $poolId,
    int $batchIndex,
    array $firebaseCredentialArray,
    array $rawFirebaseNotifs)
{

    require_once // all necessary libs ...

    require_once __DIR__ . "open_sql_co.php" ; // open a new mysql connection here  

    $factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount($firebaseCredentialArray);
    $messagingService = $factory->createMessaging();


    $firebaseMessages = [];

    foreach ($rawFirebaseNotifs as $k => $rawFirebaseNotif)
    {
        $message = [....] // preparing FCM payload here .. 
        $firebaseMessages[] = $message ;
    }


    DebugLog::info("[Pool ID : ".$poolId.", batch $batchIndex] : Sending ".count($firebaseMessages)." notifications..");
    $sendReport = $messagingService->sendAll($firebaseMessages);
    DebugLog::info("[Pool ID : ".$poolId.", batch $batchIndex] : Sent.");

    // **** mark all the notification we've sent as "sent" status in database ****
    $fromId = $rawFirebaseNotifs[0]['id'];
    $toId   = $rawFirebaseNotifs[count($rawFirebaseNotifs) - 1]['id'];

    OSQL::set("update pushnotif__queue set sta = 'sent', time_sent = now() 
                    where sending_pool_id = '$poolId' and ID >= $fromId and ID <= $toId");

    foreach($sendReport->getItems() as $k => $sendReportItem)
    {
       // processing report sent back by FCM...
    }
};







// MAIN SCRIPT :

while(1)
{
    OSQL::set("lock tables pushnotif__queue write");

    // poll database continuously
    $notifs = OSQL::get("select * from pushnotif__queue where sta = 'pending' order by ID asc"); 
                     


    if($notifs !== false)
    {
        $poolId = uniqid("", false);

        // mark them as 'sending' state and put the poolId
        OSQL::set("update pushnotif__queue set 
                            sta = 'sending', 
                            sending_pool_id = '$poolId', 
                            time_inqueue = now() 
                            where sta = 'pending' limit " . MAX_WINDOW_PER_POOL );

        // lock and unlock prevent new "pending" notification to be inserted by other part of the server while we set them to "sending" status 
        OSQL::set("unlock tables");

        $pnotifs = [] ;


        //now create one thread per group of 500 notifications

        $countBatch = ceil(count($pnotifs) / 500) ;



        $firebaseRawNotifs = [];
        foreach ($pnotifs as $k => $pnotif)
        {
            $firebaseRawNotifs[] = [
                // compute all variable the thread callback will need as primitives values/arrays 
                //(can't send objects to thread callback) 
            ];
        }


        DebugLog::info("[Pool ID : ".$poolId."] Pool of " . count($pnotifs) . " notifications found, creating " . $countBatch . " threads..  " );

        // create N thread and send them the right part ([0;500], [500-1000], ..) of the full notification array 
        for($b = 0; $b <= $countBatch - 1; $b++)
        {

            $len = $b !== $countBatch - 1 ? 500 :  $countBatch % 500;
            $batch = array_slice($firebaseRawNotifs, $b * 500, $len);

            // create the thread and send the payload of push notifs 
            parallel\run($sendNotificationBatch, [$poolId, $b,$firebaseCredentialArray, $batch] );
        }

  

    }
    else
    {
        OSQL::set("unlock tables");
        DebugLog::log("no new notification found" );
    }



    usleep(DELAY_POLL_MS * 1000);

}
```

Now comes the problem :
Sometime, I have no idea when and why, the MySQL connection gets closed **in the thread callback** only. For example, the app adds a new pending notification, I have this :

```
MySQL server has gone away[Pool ID : 5f6525d14bd02] Pool of 1 notifications found, creating 1 threads..
[Pool ID : 5f6525d14bd02, batch 0] : Sending 1 notifications..
[Pool ID : 5f6525d14bd02, batch 0] : Sent.
```

The push notification is correctly sent, with the right messages and variables so the SQL requests in the main script work well. Though, the SQL request in the thread callback doesn't run. I find my push notifications still in "sending" state.
This problem occurs after a long time. When I first execute the script, everything works well. After several hours, I have the problem.

I saw that MySQL closes TCP connection after 8 hours of inactivity, and it can output this "MySQL server has gone away". But here, a new connection is created in the thread callback, which is created at the time the notification is retrieved from main script. So I don't understand why there would be any "8 hours inactivity" here ..

Thanks for reading

Comment: Hi, it might be an issue with connection pooling. perhaps this is of interest https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/387

Comment: thank you ! looks like i'm not alone having this problem then.I'll give it a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found myself : I just forgot to close mysql connections at each thread :

```
mysqli_close($mysqlRes);
```

As it was only the thread that ended (and not the entiere script), mysql cons weren't closed, eventually accumulating until MySQL decided not to receive any more request.